# "Display localhost:0 unavailable" and "xhost: unable to open display 'localhost:0'" in local terminal (not SSH) on Fedora 25

Tags: x11, xorg

Problems of this variety are common, but I can only find answers dealing with remote machines and chroots. I am getting this error in my own terminal on Fedora 25, not while SSH'ing into a remote server.

The problem arose when I tried to run `emacs` from a terminal emulator on Fedora 25. I received the message:

```
Display localhost:0.0 unavailable, simulating -nw
```

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
```

returns

```
localhost:0.0
```

```
$ xhost +localhost
```

and

```
$ xhost +
```

both return

```
xhost:  unable to open display "localhost:0.0"
```

```
$ xinit
```

returns

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.
(EE) 
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

```
ps aux | grep `cat /tmp/.X0-lock`
```

returns

```
ryan      1764  3.6  3.2 2150384 260912 tty2   Sl+  18:04   2:15 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
ryan     11671  0.0  0.0 119372   960 pts/0    S+   19:05   0:00 grep --color=auto 1764
```

UPDATE:
 - I am not chrooting or SSHing into a remote system.
 - I am not using wayfair.
 - I am using Terminal and Terminator in Fedora 25.
 - The output of `echo $XAUTHORITY and xauth list "$@" | awk '{print $1, "", $2}'` is `/home/ryan/.Xauthority and`

Can you help me fix and understand this?

Comment: All that, and the question does not give the fairly basic item of information that is what X servers you can see running on your machine and what X displays they are serving up.  (-:

Comment: Are you using wayland?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $XAUTHORITY` and `xauth list "$@" | awk '{print $1, "", $2}'`? How do you start the shell that you run the commands from: are you launching a terminal emulator (which one) which runs a shell, or is some other software involved such as Screen or tmux?

Comment: @Gilles ```/home/ryan/.Xauthority  and```. I am using Terminal and Terminator in Fedora 25.


@Ipor No, I am not familiar with wayland.


@JdeBP Please let me know how to identify this information if it isn't provided by the command from @Gilles above.

Comment: So `xauth list` doesn't list anything? That's definitely a problem. An application knows which display to use from the `DISPLAY` environment variable, but also needs to demonstrate that it's authorized to use that display, and that's what the xauth data is about. `xauth list` should return a line for your display. Either `XAUTHORITY` is not set correctly (some configurations have the data in a different location) or something is erasing the data.

Comment: What's strange is that you can run the terminal emulator. Do you have anything in your `.bashrc` or other configuration file that overwrites environment variables that it shouldn't? If you move your `.bashrc` out of the way, does this make it possible to launch GUI programs from the shell, and what is the value of `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed .bashrc and .bash_profile and opened a window of Xterm. `xauth` then returns `Using authority file /home/ryan/.Xauthority`. `echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0`. `echo $XAUTHORITY` returns a blank line. @Gilles

Comment: And so, with `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` moved out of the way, does everything work (except your bash configuration of course)?

Comment: It seems to be working, unless it's a problem that `echo $XAUTHORITY` returns only a newline.

Here are potentially relevant lines in my .bash_profile:

`export PATH="/usr/lib/X11:$PATH"`
`# Fix x-window problems`
`export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`
`export XAUTHORITY=/home/ryan/.Xauthority`

@Gilles. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between DISPLAY values `:0.0` and `localhost:0.0`.

The `:0.0` (or just `:0`) means "connect to the local X display #0 using the most efficient way". This can mean a UNIX socket for the initial connection, then (optionally) negotiating a shared-memory-based connection for higher performance.

The `localhost:0.0` value means "connect to the local X display #0 **using a TCP socket** in port 6000" (port number = display number + 6000). Because the default X server configuration in most Linux distributions released in this century has TCP connections disabled, this is unlikely to work without specifically enabling TCP access to the X server first.

And unless you are in a secure network and know what you're doing, **you should not enable TCP access to the X server**. In a properly configured modern system, there should be no reason whatsoever to do that.

The normal ways for starting an X11 session will usually set the DISPLAY environment variable for you automatically. If you think you need to keep setting it as a routine operation (in `.bashrc` or similar), you're probably doing something in a non-optimal way.

Answer (score 1):

For me this works

```
export DISPLAY=':0'
```

for example I cannot open gedit or evince or anything graphical use terminal, but above solution is enough